# Altering registration database mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

new here and pretty new to mvc and visual studio also. My query is this: in a mobile based web application project; i wish to have newly registered users store their geolocation on bing maps alongside their details and regularly update-able offers.

I then need users of the site that do not register to be able to view these locations and details based on their own coordinates. Can i add tables to the existing registration and login database and query everything from there or do i need to create another database?

i am using visual studio 2012 express and mvc3

sorry if this is a bit vague...